# Why does active_support requires sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra

I don't use sinatra anywhere in my app, its not clear why activesupport mandates needing sinatra. How should I avoid this problem

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@app/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- sinatra/base (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 3):

Active Support doesn't require sinatra. However, since active support is the bit of rails that handles missing constants (and as such patches `require`) it will show up in the stack trace when require fails.

Comment: Somewhere something is requiring Sinatra/base or using Sinatra::Base. I'd search through your code for that. The rest of the stack trace may have clues

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely a dependency of another gem. For example, resque uses Sinatra to display monitoring. You can use `gem dependency` to find these.